# JavaScript date mask to MySQL date

Tags: jquery, date, maskedtextbox

I want to mask a date input to mm/dd/yyyy. When the form submits, i want to convert that to YYYY-MM-DD for mysql.

Would it be best to change the value of the input field, or have hidden inputs that store the conversion and use the value of the hidden field?

Is there a known jquery plugin for this? Is that known as a reverse mask?

Comment: In my opinion, it would be best to accept the date as-is and convert it on the server-side. This is in line with the general principle that you should ALWAYS validate form data server-side anyway.

Comment: good call. thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to me that it would be best to take the input from the form and parse it to the correct date type in the form code, not the frontend.